Today, VS Code has started underlining my inline CSS classes in Vue 3 components. How can I remove this?
Not sure, why, tried disabling all extensions to check, and checked in preferences, but as of this morning my Vue 3 component has underlines for classes, regardless of color theme. Like so:

Any coffee injected ideas as to how I can remove these darn underlines from the css classes.
Thanks in advance!

It may be an extension that does that, which you could find using the Bisect command from the Command Palette

I will answer my own question as I found the setting in preferences. Untick this and you're sorted:

Peace, T
